# How to verify if a button is clickable with Selenium in Python when the class changes?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find out if a "Ship to Home" button is available and able to be clicked on an item in The Home Depot website. Currently, the only identifier that I find for the button is a class but when you go from store pickup to ship to home the two classes switch places for the button element.
[Two Elements Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1iF.png)

This is even more confusing when the "ship to home" option is unavailable and contains an even more different class. [Unavailable Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Nmx.png)

I'm trying to avoid using xpath as I am afraid the it might change locations in the future and I would have to constantly update it. I don't know much about selenium but I'm assuming there has to be some type of way to loop a section of the HTML and find out if the element contains some text and if it does to click on that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPATH could be quite flexible and allows to refer a lot of element node's data and also in advance it alows some logical conditions, etc. So I believe it's very powerful and flexible enough to produce some targeted and not fragile results.

Regarding your case:

```
clickable_button_xpath = "//a[@type='button'][contains(., 'Ship to Home') and contains(@class, '-unselected')]"
selected_button_xpath = "//a[@type='button'][contains(., 'Ship to Home') and contains(@class, '-selected')]"
unclickable_button_xpath = "//a[@type='button'][contains(., 'Ship to Home') and contains(@class, '-unclickable')]"

some_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, some_xpath)
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you.